# Begin Loop from ActiveCell

Tags: vba, excel

Is there a way to begin populating  set of values from where the function was called from?

```
Function score2(TYP)
If TYP = "1" Then
    Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 10 Step 1

    ActiveCell.Condition = 1

   Next
End If
End Function
```

Comment: you can't really use a function to populate cells others then the one the function is being called from

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to know from which cell the function was called. `Application.Caller` gives you the cell.

But there is no way to change sheet from a function that is called from a sheet. Use a separate macro for that, and trigger it in response to an event, not during sheet calculation.